# Pytorch lightning metrics: ValueError: preds and target must have same number of dimensions, or one additional dimension for preds

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, cross-entropy, pytorch-lightning

Googling this gets you no where, so I decided to help future me and others by posting this as a searchable question.

---

```
def __init__():
    ...
    self.val_acc = pl.metrics.Accuracy()

def validation_step(self, batch, batch_index):
    ...
    self.val_acc.update(log_probs, label_batch)
```

gives

```
ValueError: preds and target must have same number of dimensions, or one additional dimension for preds
```

for `log_probs.shape == (16, 4)` and for `label_batch.shape == (16, 4)`

What's the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pl.metrics.Accuracy()` expects a batch of `dtype=torch.long` labels, not one-hot encoded labels.

Thus, it should be fed

`self.val_acc.update(log_probs, torch.argmax(label_batch.squeeze(), dim=1))`

---

This is just the same as `torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss`